# Automatically scroll the listview from top to bottom in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listview

Good day guys.

I am currently creating a some kind of advertisement app. It is simple text scrolling from top to bottom and will repeat again. I am currently using listview to do this in c#. The texts that will show in the listview will be coming from a database. I am using the timer to automatically refresh the form. The problem is how can I move it or scroll it from top to bottom automatically every time the form loads and will repeat again every time it finished.

Thank you.

This is the code so far as requested by Mr. King King.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
        listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().LastOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: means you want auto scrolling list ? btw what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've put the codes in the timer function. What I want to inquire is it possible is there something like listview.selecteditem += 1 in listview so that every time the timer ticks the listview will scroll automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `ListView.TopItem` to the last item and it should ensure the scrollbar to be at the bottom:

```
listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count-1];
```

You should be sure your `listView1` has at least 1 item, here is a LINQ version which is safer:

```
listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().LastOrDefault();
```

### UPDATE

If you want to scroll from top to bottom by each item, try this:

```
int lastIndex;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
    int i = listView1.TopItem == null ? -1 : listView1.TopItem.Index;        
    if(i>-1) {
      if(i == lastIndex || i == listView1.Items.Count - 2) i = 0;
      lastIndex = i;
      listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items[++i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. But the codes that you share made the listview scrolled in the last part only. (I've placed your code in the timer function together with the refresh function) It doesn't move at all. Is there something like listview.selectedindex += 1 every time the timer ticks?

Comment: @LucasJuan what do you mean by `scrolled in the last part only`? The code works OK for me, the only condition is your `ListView` has to have `View` as `List` or `Details`.

Comment: @LucasJuan if possible, you should post your actual code, the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: What I mean sir is it just stay in last item in the list. It doesn't move like what I want to be. One item per second.

Comment: @LucasJuan it's not clear, do you mean if your listview has 4 items, you want to scroll from item1, next to item2, item3, and then stops at item4?

Comment: Yes sir, and if it reached item4, it will start again from item1.

Comment: wow You're the man. Thanks! I know that it is a bit too much already but I want to learn. How did you come up with that solution? Can you explain it? if you don't mind? Thanks!

Comment: @LucasJuan the point is we increase the top index (corresponds to `TopItem`) in each Tick of the Timer. However the code above just stops at last item, it does not turn back to the first item, do you want that?

Comment: Yes sir If you don't mind it and if I am not asking too much.

Comment: @LucasJuan updated, it's a little more complicated than the last requirement.

Comment: sir the lastIndex does not exist in the current context, How should I fix it?

Comment: @LucasJuan you missed the `lastIndex` which is declared as a private `int` field of your form class.

Comment: You are really great sir, You are right sir the update you just did make it harder for my small brain to understand. Can you give me some advise sir how to learn more about c#?

Comment: @LucasJuan firstly we need the so-called **love** :), each programmer has different levels of skills, but they have the same one called **love** for programming. Secondly, you need to learn it step by step, try reading some books from novice to expert about c#, it helps you understand all features of C#, you can also learn the .NET framework at the same time, in fact mastering .NET framework is the most difficult thing, it has too many stuff, fortunately it is organized in a neat and clever way so that we can manage to learn more easily. Learning from examples is also a very good way.

Answer (score 4):

After adding an item:

```
listView.EnsureVisible(listView.Items.Count - 1);
```