# WPF: auto scroll VlistView to last item

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

So in my application I am open specific process, read its output and put it inside my `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="listViewResults"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> results;
```

**Process output**

```
private void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (line != null)
    {
        results.Add(line);
    }    
}
```

So I created another `property`:

```
private string currentLog;
public string CurrentLog
{
    get { return currentLog; }
    set
    {
        currentLog = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentLog");
    }
}
```

And add it inside my OutputHandler `method`:

```
CurrentLog = line;
```

And use it in my `ListView` SelectedItem `property` in my `XAML`:

```
<ListView Name="listViewResults"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLog}"/>
```

And the result is that I still need to scroll down manually.

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209689/automatically-scroll-the-listview-from-top-to-bottom-in-c-sharp/20209800

Comment: I am using WPF, any chance to do this using XAML instead of code behind ?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting an item in a `ListView` does not automatically scroll it into view and you cannot do that in XAML only, but there is an alternative to code-behind. You can write a custom behavior. A behavior is a resusable component that you can attach to a control in XAML.

In order to do that, install the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) Nuget package to your project. Then create a type that derives from `Behavior<ListView>` like this.

```
public class ScrollIntoSelectedItemBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
      base.OnAttached();
      AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
      base.OnDetaching();
      AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
   }

   private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      var selectedItem = AssociatedObject.SelectedItem;
      if (selectedItem != null)
         AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(selectedItem);
   }
}
```

The `OnAttach` method will be called when the behavior is attached to a `ListView` control. Then it listens for selection changes and scrolls into the currently selected item, if there is one.

The cool thing about behaviors is that they do not reside in your code-behind and you can reuse them on any compatible control. To attach the behavior to your `ListView`, do this.

```
<ListView Name="listViewResults"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLog}">
   <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:ScrollIntoSelectedItemBehavior/>
   </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Add the XML namespace for the `Interaction` type to your XAML file.

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

That's it. When you set a different `CurrentLog` item, it will be scrolled into view automatically.

---

I also want to point out a potential issue in your design. Your `Results` collection contains items of type `string`. If there are duplicate items, you will encounter unexpected behavior.

Let item 42 be `"Test"` and you add item 102 that also spells `"Test"`, the list will be scrolled to item 42, because **both items are equal** and the first one in the list wins. In order to solve this issue, you have to create a custom data type as a wrapper for the actual `string`, e.g.:

```
public MyDataItem
{
   public string Log { get; }

   public MyDataItem(string log)
   {
      Log = log;
   }

   // ...
}
```

This will work, as references will be compared instead of strings and they are unique.

Comment: @DanaYeger What exactly is not working? Are your result items added and displayed in the `ListView`? Is the `SelectedItem` set to the currently added item, e.g. do you see the selection changing in the `ListView`? Your `OutputHandler` method does not show that you assign the new item to `CurrentLog`.

Comment: i can see the new item added into my list but i need to manually scroll, i am using this CurrentLog and also bind it into my ListView as i show in my post

Comment: @DanaYeger Do you **see** the selection changing to the newly added item live in your `ListView` when an item is added?

Comment: No i dont see it and i am not using any style

Comment: @DanaYeger That was what I thought. The issue is not in the behavior, but that either your binding is not working, the `CurrentLog` property is not set or not set correctly or the property changed event for it is not raised or raised for the wrong property or not implemented correctly. Look for typos in the property name. Are there binding errors in the output window?

Comment: I post the using of my CurrentLog, what can be wong here ?

Comment: @DanaYeger It seems to be okay, except that you do not set the `CurrentLog` property in the `OutputHandler`, so it is never set. Other than that, I do not know how you implemented `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

For debugging the issue, set a breakpoint in the setter of `CurrentLog` and check if it is called everytime a new item is added.

Comment: OK i did it and it seems all OK, I also bind CurrentLog to simple Label and i can see the Label changing

Comment: Unfortunately no, this CurrentLog works and changed its value but the ListView not scrolling automatically, BTW duplicate items never occurred because i add time stamp before each line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222513/discussion-between-thatguy-and-dana-yeger).